# ARC [rewriter] NSInvocation's setArgument is not safe to be used with an object with ownership other than __unsafe_unretained

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, nsinvocation

I been to convert my project to ARC and i m stuck with this error.

&object,&invocation and &callerToRetain is showing me error of "[rewriter] NSInvocation's setArgument is not safe to be used with an object with ownership other than __unsafe_unretained"

```
+ (void)performSelector:(SEL)selector onTarget:(id *)target withObject:(id)object amount:(void *)amount callerToRetain:(id)callerToRetain{if ([*target respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSMethodSignature *signature = nil;
    signature = [*target methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];

    [invocation setSelector:selector];

    int argumentNumber = 2;

    // If we got an object parameter, we pass a pointer to the object pointer
    if (object) {
        [invocation setArgument:&object atIndex:argumentNumber];
        argumentNumber++;
    }

    // For the amount we'll just pass the pointer directly so NSInvocation will call the method using the number itself rather than a pointer to it
    if (amount) {
        [invocation setArgument:amount atIndex:argumentNumber];
    }

    SEL callback = @selector(performInvocation:onTarget:releasingObject:);
    NSMethodSignature *cbSignature = [ASIHTTPRequest methodSignatureForSelector:callback];
    NSInvocation *cbInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:cbSignature];
    [cbInvocation setSelector:callback];
    [cbInvocation setTarget:self];
    [cbInvocation setArgument:&invocation atIndex:2];
    [cbInvocation setArgument:&target atIndex:3];
    if (callerToRetain) {
        [cbInvocation setArgument:&callerToRetain atIndex:4];
    }

    CFRetain(invocation);

    // Used to pass in a request that we must retain until after the call
    // We're using CFRetain rather than [callerToRetain retain] so things to avoid earthquakes when using garbage collection
    if (callerToRetain) {
        CFRetain(callerToRetain);
    }
    [cbInvocation performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
}}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you get past this in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `NSInvocation` by default does not retain or copy given arguments for efficiency, so each object passed as argument must still live when the invocation is invoked. That means the pointers passed to -setArgument:atIndex: are handled as __unsafe_unretained.

If you use `NSInvocation` in ARC, the simplest way to get it working is

1. call `[invocation retainArguments]` after creating the invocation object. That means the invocation will retain the given arguments.
2. When passing the arguments, cast them to `__unsafe_unretained`.
3. There is no step 3.